# How can I get date with javascript from rich:calendar?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, richfaces

I want to get the date from a rich:calendar component in javascript in order to compare it with another date and disable the dates which are over or under each other ("from" date can't be after "to" date) I know how to disable dates, but I haven't been able to get the date,
I've tried with:

```
#{rich:element('FromDate')}.component.getSelectedDate().getTime()
#{rich:component('FromDate')}.getSelectedDate().getTime()
#{rich:component('FromDate')}.Date.getTime()
#{rich:component('FromDate')}.getTime()
```

the idea is to after it make a comparation like

```
function disablementFunction(day){
    if (#{rich:element('FromDate')}.component.getSelectedDate().getTime() -
      day.date.getTime() &gt;= 0) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Richfaces js api to get the current date:

```
RichFaces.$('FromDate').currentDate.getTime()
```

Just for clarification your code snippet will become something like:

```
function disablementFunction(day){
    if (RichFaces.$('FromDate').currentDate.getTime() >= 0) { 
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Of Course you can still refer to this date using el expression:

```
#{rich:component('FromDate')}.currentDate.getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you but your code has a small problem, current date gives me just the month :S what I actually used was selecteddate RichFaces.$('FromDate').selectedDate.getTime() - day.date.getTime() &gt;= 0

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>

    <rich:calendar id="clndUATOnDateId" datePattern="dd-MMM-yyyy"></rich:calendar>

    <h:commandButton title="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="addUATDates();"></h:commandButton>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addUATDates() {
            var uatOn = document.getElementById("addUATDateForm:clndUATOnDateIdInputDate");
            alert(uatOn.value);
        }
    </script>
```

Write 'InputDate' after clndUATOnDateId in script to get date.
        The output of selected rich calendar date (Ex: 15-Sep-2012) is dispalyed in alert popup.